# text to speech audio not matching the source?

Tags: text-to-speech

i am testing many text to speech and the audio exported not matching the source length.

using capcut or online free service to generate text to speech however the length is not matching.

i export subtitles in txt and add to text to speech and i get length not matching issue.

i was thinking about srt now. i have srt with time stamps. what service can i use to import the srt and use text to speech ?

srt example

```
{QTtext} {font:Tahoma}
{plain} {size:20}
{timeScale:30}
{width:160} {height:32}
{timestamps:absolute} {language:0}
[00:00:00.06]
Created Adam the first man out of clay and breathed life into him.
[00:00:04.06]

[00:00:05.04]
He then created Eve the first woman from Adam's rib created to live
[00:00:10.04]

[00:00:10.04]
in the garden of Eden,
[00:00:11.04]

[00:00:11.05]
a paradise on earth where they were free to enjoy everything that was there except for one tree that
[00:00:16.03]

[00:00:16.03]
Allah had forbidden them to eat for who was jealous of Adam and Eve
[00:00:20.21]

[00:00:20.22]
tempted them and convinced them to eat from the forbidden tree.
[00:00:23.19]

[00:00:24.16]
He disobeyed Allah's command and committed the first sin in human history as a
[00:00:29.12]

[00:00:29.12]
result.
[00:00:30.02]

[00:00:30.00]
He became aware of the inkiness and felt shame.
[00:00:32.15]

[00:00:33.12]
They tried to cover themselves with leaves,
[00:00:35.12]

[00:00:35.12]
but all they had already seen what they had done had warned Adam and Eve that if they
[00:00:40.09]
```

```
{QTtext} {font:Tahoma}
{plain} {size:20}
{timeScale:30}
{width:160} {height:32}
{timestamps:absolute} {language:0}
[00:00:00.06]
Created Adam the first man out of clay and breathed life into him.
[00:00:04.06]

[00:00:05.04]
He then created Eve the first woman from Adam's rib created to live
[00:00:10.04]

[00:00:10.04]
in the garden of Eden,
[00:00:11.04]

[00:00:11.05]
a paradise on earth where they were free to enjoy everything that was there except for one tree that
[00:00:16.03]

[00:00:16.03]
Allah had forbidden them to eat for who was jealous of Adam and Eve
[00:00:20.21]

[00:00:20.22]
tempted them and convinced them to eat from the forbidden tree.
[00:00:23.19]

[00:00:24.16]
He disobeyed Allah's command and committed the first sin in human history as a
[00:00:29.12]

[00:00:29.12]
result.
[00:00:30.02]

[00:00:30.00]
He became aware of the inkiness and felt shame.
[00:00:32.15]

[00:00:33.12]
They tried to cover themselves with leaves,
[00:00:35.12]

[00:00:35.12]
but all they had already seen what they had done had warned Adam and Eve that if they
[00:00:40.09]
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "not matching the source length".  What does "source length" mean if you are starting from text?

Comment: If these are subtitles in language A for speech in language B, then of course text-to-speech in language A will not match speech in language B.  Different languages, plus the subtitles are a translation.  Even for the same language, different speaker will speak at different rates.